# Why does this constraint behave differently on different simulators?

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I ran across the following constraint in a testbench. It's behavior seems to vary depending on the simulator used.

```
constraint wr_c {
    if (!one_beat) { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 };
}
```

What is it actually supposed to do, as written?

An example:

```
import uvm_pkg::*;

class pkt extends uvm_object;

  rand bit one_beat;
  rand int len;
  rand bit [31:0] addr;

  `uvm_object_utils_begin(pkt)
    `uvm_field_int(one_beat, UVM_DEFAULT)
    `uvm_field_int(len, UVM_DEFAULT)
    `uvm_field_int(addr, UVM_DEFAULT)
  `uvm_object_utils_end

  constraint wr_c {
    if (!one_beat) { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 };
  } 

endclass

module test;

  initial begin
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) begin
      automatic pkt p = new();
      p.randomize();
      p.print();
    end
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: How about explaining the different behaviors you are seeing?

Comment: @dave_59, based on Greg's answer, I added an answer describing what happens with different simulators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the different simulator give different results likely has to do with what it constitutes as `true` for the solver. Using the following example:

```
rand bit [1:0] example;
rand bit one_beat;
constraint example_c { if(!one_beat) example; }
```

In this case `example` has the same randomization width as `{ addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 }`. Depending on the simulator the above constraint may infer `example==2'b1` or `example!=2'b0` or `example>2'b0` (different results with signed and unsigned) . If `one_beat` wasn't an one-bit value, the same issue would be true for want counts as true for the `if()` statement.

If the **OR** option is intended, a better way to write the constraint would be:

```
if (!one_beat) ( addr[5:0] == 0  ||  len == 15 );
```

or

```
if (!one_beat) { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 } != 0; // or '>0', '>=1', etc
```

There is a good change the creator of the constraint intended both constraints to be true when `if(!one_beat)`. In this case the follow would be better constraint options:

```
if (!one_beat) { addr[5:0] == 0; len == 15; } // note the semicolon positions
```

or

```
if (!one_beat) ( addr[5:0] == 0 && len == 15 );
```

---

Also note that with the given SSCCE, `one_beat` has a very low probability of being `1'b0` because the solver is trying to find a legal condition for `one_beat`, `addr` and `len` in parallel with equal priority.

- When `addr[5:0]==0 || len==15` its probability is `1/(1+2**6) + 1/(1+2**32)`
- When `addr[5:0]==0 && len==15` its probability is `1/(1+2**(6+32))`

If this is not intend, then add another constraint such as `one_beat dist { ... };` or `sovle one_beat before addr,len;`

- `constraints` [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.5 *Constrained random value generation*
- `dist {...}` [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.5.4 *Distribution*
- `solve ... before ...` [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.5.10 *Variable ordering*

Answer (score 1):

This is how the constraint behaves on different simulators. The constraint behaves differently because the simulators treat the concatenation constraint `{a, b};` in different ways.

The code below is pseudo code for purposes of demonstrating how the constraint from the question works.

On VCS 2013.06:

```
if (!one_beat) { 
  { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 } == 2'b01 || { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 } == 2'b10;
  // distribution highly favors 2'b01
}
```

On Questa SIM 10.1d:

```
if (!one_beat) { 
  { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 } == 2'b10;
}
```

On INCISIV 13.10.001:

```
if (!one_beat) { 
  { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 } == 2'b01 || { addr[5:0] == 0, len == 15 } == 2'b10;
  // distribution favors 2'b10
}
```

Comment: The favoring of `2'b10` makes sense with the default weighting. `addr[5:0]==0` has a probability of `1/(1+2**6)` which is greater the the probably of `len==15` (`1/(1+2**32)`). Reverse the order of `addr` & `len` in the constraint and `1'b01` will be favored. Use `dist {}` to control the distribution. Ex `{address[5:0]==0,len==25} dist { 1:=3, 2:=2};`

Comment: Also, what is the distribution favoring with Questa? Shouldn't this  information be in the question?

Comment: For Questa, it is always `addr[5:0] == 0 && len != 15 when !one_beat`. This info could be in the question, although it practically answers the question.